# How to access dispose method from fields that are in auto implemented properties

Tags: c#, .net, memory, .net-4.0

Why is it that I can access the dispose method inside the Bmw  getter setter method but not in the dispose() method?

How then can I dispose of the following fields below:?

```
Class Car: IDisposable
 {

    private FontWeight bmw;

     public FontWeight Bmw
                {
                   bmw.Dispose(); <<<<<<<< Can access Dispose
                    get
                    { return bmw; }
                    set
                    { bmw= value;

                    }

                    public void Dispose(){
                      bmw.Dispose(); <<<< Cant access Dispose()
                    }                        
                }
            }
```

Comment: Would'n that cause an infinite loop? to be calling the same method inside the same method..

Comment: The code you've posted is invalid in a number of ways. You're trying to declare the `Dispose` method *inside the property* for one thing.

Comment: and also calling the dispose method inside the property outside of a getter and setter - @Xikinho90 - no it wouldn't be an infinity loop, since he just wants to call `Dispose` on the variable

Comment: Im pretty aware of that I just need to access the dispose method in public void Dispose() to dispose of bmw. but it wont appear as in contrast to the dispose method appearing in the property method

Answer (score 2):

If that is your code, than you have a ton of syntax errors inside:

```
public FontWeight Bmw
{
    /// here shouldn't be any code, just getters and setters
    get { return bmw; }
    set { bmw = value; }

    /// you forgot to close the property here
} /// now it's closed

public void Dispose()
{
    bmw.Dispose(); /// now it will work
}
```

Comment: this  answer destroys the very reason I posted the problem in the first place because it points out the problem I am specifying.

Comment: FontWeight is a windows class

Comment: @user2708073, it is not clear HOW you want to be using the dispose. Also, why are you trying to dispose your object *within itself?*.